# "NOT LIKE x" and "LIKE x" doesn't sum up?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like, oracle12c

I don't quite get it...

Could somebody please give me a hint on why the results of queries B + C won't add-up to A?

I first thought, that the amount of underscores (should be ten) mismatch between B and C because of a typo, but after copy/pasting I am a bit helpless. The result of A is higher than the sum of B + C.

Is there some kind of implicit distinct etc. in statement B and C that I am not aware of?

```
-- statement A
select count(*) from mytable;

-- statement B
select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn like '__________';

-- statement C
select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn not like '__________';
```

Comment: There are probably NULL values in that column

Comment: Oh yeah, guys, you're great! :) There is a german saying "Vor lauter Bäumen den Wald nicht sehen". Thank's!!

Comment: Always be thoughtfull of NULL values! If you learn only 1 thing today, this may be one thing to learn, and remember for ever !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If mycolumn has some rows with `NULL` values, those will be excluded from both `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` clauses.

Therefore, those 2 statements should be equal:

```
SELECT (select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn like '__________')
+ (select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn not like '__________')
+ (select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn IS NULL)
FROM DUAL

-- is equal to

select count(*) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your mycolumn contains NULL values.
NULL values won't compare to LIKE or NOT LIKE.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the result of this, it will add up:

```
select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn is null;
```

The reason behind this is that `null` is considered 'undefined'. So you can't say something *you don't know* is *like*, or *not like* something else. It is undefined. Comparison to null, except when using `is null` will always return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your column contains NULL values. When you compare *anything* to NULL (even another NULL), the result is `false`.

So in your example, there are those that are like your pattern, those that are not like your pattern and the NULL values, that are neither.